# Setting background color for entire line in a NSTextView

Tags: macos, cocoa, background-color, nstextview

Let's say that my NSTextView contains the following text:

> Header Text For Section
>
> This is some text for this section. Just about anything could be here.

So, I can easily set the background color of the text 'Header Text For Section' as shown here:

[image: Current]

but the color ends at the end of the text and I would like it to extend to the end of the line as shown here:

[image: Desired]

What I am hoping is that this can be done without subclassing, but I expect subclassing will be necessary.

Comment: I would like to see a solution that *also* turns the little white margin (to the left of the 'H' in "Header") the same color. But leaves the margin on other lines the default white.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try extending the color attribute (style run) to include the linefeed character at the end of the line.

Comment: Can you please explain me with more details? I am not so expert and I am not able to understand this answer. Thank you.

Comment: You might set the background color of part of a text view like this (Objective-C): `[textview.textStorage addAttribute: NSBackgroundColorAttributeName value: [NSColor redColor] range: NSMakeRange( startOffset, colorLength)]`.  I'm just saying that the length of the range should include the invisible line break field at the end of the line.